# Getting ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver in one but not in another class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

On executing below code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm getting exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

I've already imported all tomcat jars & ojdbc14.jar.

Weird thing is when I write same code in a separate class in main(), it works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        System.out.println("works");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you place the jars under `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your container ?

Comment: Presumably when you're executing via the `main` method, you're in a *completely* different execution environment, picking up its classpath in an entirely different way.

Comment: Where do you place the driver's jar (ojdbc14.jar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you did not place the ojdbc14.jar at right location. It should reside in Web-INF/lib folder where your other project specific jar lies. For debugging purpose try to import the class and see below statement is interpreted correctly

```
OracleDriver od=   new OracleDriver();
```

Answer (score 1):

There might several options

Options :

1. Make sure to put `ojdbcxx.jar` file under `WEB-INF/lib` directory.
2. Put `ojdbcxx.jar` under `<tomcat home dir>/common/lib`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand calling mechanism of main() and doPost.

main()

The java tool launches a Java application. It does this by starting a Java runtime environment, loading a specified class, and invoking that class's main method.

build path for this is where you have your Java code, so lib should be present here.

doPost()

It is invoked by Server.

Structure of it is

```
          App Name  
              -WEB-INF
                   -classes (all class file)
                   -lib (all jars) 
              -META-INF
```

So here, jar you need to place is in lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `servlet` is set to early initialization. put `ojdbc14.jar` in tomcat `lib` directory or set `servlet` to lazy initialization.